# When i call ajax function its working first time only in first ajax call i reload the same div from which i m calling ajax request

Tags: ajax

```
// main htm page from where aja x call happened
    <div id ="vote_count_<%=answer.id %>"  >
     <%= render :partial => '/votes/count', :locals =>{ :answer => answer} %>//render a partial
     <div id="wait" style=" float:center">// for loading image
     </div>
    </div>

   // partial page :- count

    <div class ="look6">
      <%= image_tag("thumbs_up.jpg", :alt =>  "like",:value => answer.id,:id => 'like',:class => 'vote')%>// image tag for like reload during ajax call
      (<%= Vote.count(answer.id,'like')%>)// no of like vote
      | <%= image_tag("thumbs_down.jpg", :alt =>  "unlike",:value => answer.id,:id     =>'unlike',:class => 'vote',:onclick=>"return vote()") %>// image tag for unlike reload during ajax call
      (<%= Vote.count(answer.id,'unlike')%>)// no of unlike vote
    </div>


  //  ajax function :-

    <script type="text/javascript" >

      function showLoadingImage()
      {

        $('#wait').append('<div id="loading-image"><%= image_tag("ajax-loader.gif", :alt=>"Loading..." )%></div>');// for ajax loading
      }
    in first page:
//.vote is a claas name
      $(".vote").click(function(){
        alert("hi");
        var answer_id =$(this).attr("value");// for ans id
        alert(answer_id);
        showLoadingImage();// call loading image function
        var result = $(this).attr("id");// whether like or unlike
        $.ajax({

          cache: false,
    //path for controller
          url: '/create_vote/'+answer_id, 
          data: "result="+result,// data for ajax call
          complete: function(){
            $('#loading-image').remove();// remove loading image

          }

        });
        cache: false;
         return false;
      });
    </script>

    //ontroller:

    def create_vote
        @vote = Vote.new // create new vot
        @vote.user_id = current_user.id// user id
        @vote.answer_id = params[:id]// answer id
        @vote.result = params[:result] == 'like' ? '1':'0'// like or unlike
        answer = Answer.find(params[:id])// answer id find
        if @vote.save// save vote
         @message  = "thanks"// message 
        else
         @message =  "sorry"// mesage
        end

        @vote_count = Vote.count(params[:id], params[:result])// total vote
          respond_to do |format|
            format.js  { render '/votes/create_vote.js.erb', :locals => {:result =>params[:result],:answer =>answer}}// result return back 
          end
        end
```

///votes/create_vote.js.erb
$("#vote_count_<%=@vote.answer_id %>").html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => '/votes/count', :locals => {:result => result ,:answer =>answer }) %>")// render js part

//_count partial
<%= image_tag("thumbs_up.jpg", :alt =>  "like",:value => answer.id,:id => 'like',:class => 'vote')%>
  (<%= Vote.count(answer.id,'like')%>)
  | <%= image_tag("thumbs_down.jpg", :alt =>  "unlike",:value => answer.id,:id =>'unlike',:class => 'vote',:onclick=>"return vote()") %>
  (<%= Vote.count(answer.id,'unlike')%>)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:- `$(".vote").live("click", function(){`

in place of :  `$(".vote").click(function(){`